# controller from another module not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

Hey so I am having a problem trying to get my child controller working. Basically I have created 2 modules in total. 1 for handling my directives and controllers for them and another to handle my gmail side of things.

```
//js file 
1 var gmailMod =  angular.module('gmailMod', []);

gmailMod.controller('gmailCtrl',function gmailCtrl(gmailFactory){

   this.authorize = function(){

       console.log("clicking");
       //gmailFactory.gmailAuthorize();
   }
});

//jsFile2
var emailModule = angular.module('emailMod', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

I have a third file called config that declares the dependencies

```
angular.module('seamysApp', ['ngRoute', 'emailMod', 'gmailMod'])
```

So anyways the email Mod works perfectly but when I try to declare a child controller on my button form the gmailMod

```
<div ng-controller="gmailCtrl">
  <button ng-click="authorize()" class="btn-info" >Not authorized yet! Click here! :)</button>
</div>
```

Nothing works. I can't get the authorize function to work. Why is this happening does anyone know? I'm getting no errors in my console so I think it must be some logical error by me and it's difficult to find. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you have any instance of "gmailCtrl"? I mean, do you have ng-controller="gmailCtrl" in your HTML?

Comment: Ya I do....... see the above <div ng-controller="gmailCtrl">
  <button ng-click="authorize()" class="btn-info" >Not authorized yet! Click here! :)</button>
</div>

That's part of a directive I am trying to call. The main part of the templates controller comes from the emailModule file but that specific button needs to have a different controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div ng-controller="gmailCtrl as gCtrl">
  <button ng-click="gCtrl.authorize()" class="btn-info" >Not authorized yet! Click here! :)</button>
</div>`